# Communication between multiple scaled-out Azure AppService instances

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-web-app-service, azure-table-storage

I am running an Azure AppService (ASP.NET 4.6 WebApi at the moment) that is always running on at least 2 instances and - using auto-scaling - scales out to a maximum of 5 instances.

This very app is dealing with a lot of data that is stored in Azure Tables and lots of those tables are pretty static. They are updated once or twice a month but are read thousands of times during daily operation. As I'm trying to improve the performance of that service a bit, I was thinking about caching those "static" tables in memory and updating them only when new changes get pushed to the storage. This would not be a problem because changes to the storage are made solely through that same API though `/POST` calls.

But now I am wondering how to deal with this architecture when running multiple instances of my service. I obviously cannot predict which instance responds to my `/POST` call and all other instances will not be notified of the change.

I also do not want to write states / semaphores to any kind of shared storage, as that would defeat the whole purpose of trying to reduce storage calls.

Any hints how I could make these instances somehow "communicate" between each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to externalize the state into a store like Redis, which would be shared by all instances of the app service. So, all of the reads would be from the Redis store and writes would entail both updating Table Storage and the entry in Redis.

**UPDATE: The following approach doesn't work well when auto scaling out but can be replaced with [Azure Web PubSub](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-web-pubsub/overview) instead to handle such scenarios**

Another approach would be to use a Message Broker like [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview) and have the entries in-memory in each app service instance.

You would setup [one topic and multiple subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions), one for each App Service instance to listen on for new messages.

When storage is updated, the instance that handled the request would insert a message into the topic, which all instances would receive and then go ahead to fetch the latest from table storage.

This allows for a pull kind of model where since the instances are already connected to the Service Bus instance, the sender of the message doesn't have to know how many instances are present to notify the others.

Comment: I found it to be a promising idea, but it doesn't work well with AppService and scale out. Because if I run topic + subscriptions, all instances will connect to the same subscription and only one of them will get the message. It would require me to automatically create new subscriptions whenever a scale-out happens, which is dangerous because it requires elevated credentials.

Comment: My bad. That is true when auto-scaling. You could also consider [Azure Web PubSub](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-web-pubsub/overview), which is a WebSockets gateway and handles the scale out scenario here since new instances would just connect, and publishers would just broadcast to all.

Comment: In the end I've gone with the normal topic-subscriber pattern and create subscribers as I required them. I keep track of them in a storage account with a timeout so I am always able to find any orphaned ones. As for security: it's a connection string that is never shared, so it's as secure as any other connection string I use on the app.